# Confused about by this nested for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, bubble-sort

Why does this for loop print / sort all 10 integers. 
It starts off with i = N - 1 which is greater than or equal to 0 so it goes on to the next for loop. Here J is 1 which is less than or equal to i so it compiles.

The issue i'm having is that the first iteration would be 
i=9 and j = 1, 
8 and 2, 
7 and 3, 
6 and 4, 
5 and 5
and finally 4 and 6 (stopping point),

where j is not less than or equal to i. Shouldn't it only compile for the amount of times that it runs so 5 times instead of the 10 that it does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[10] = { 3,6,1,2,3,8,4,1,7,2};

void bubble(int a[], int N);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    putchar('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    bubble(arr,10);
    putchar('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void bubble(int a[], int N)
{
    int i, j, t;
    for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (a[j-1] > a[j])
            {
                t = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The specific code that i'm not wrapping my head around is

```
for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (a[j-1] > a[j])
        {
            t = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is correct and returns the correct array of sorted intergers

Comment: `j` always starts at 1.

Comment: You can try using printf statements inside your for loops and walking through what i and j are in each iteration, to understand how the logic is executing. In your case, regardless of what i is, j starts at 1 and will execute from 1 to i.

Comment: Punch "bubble sort" into your favorite search engine so that you understand the algorithm. Then try to understand the code.

Comment: Each outer iteration moves the greatest element in the current range to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 loops are nested. The behaviour is that for each iteration of the outer loop, the full inner loop runs. That means that for a fixed i, j takes values from 1 to i:

```
i = 9, j = 1;
i = 9, j = 2;
i = 9, j = 3;
...
i = 9, j = 9;
```

Now the execution finishes on the inner loop and goes back to the outer, decrementing i.

```
i = 8, j = 1;
i = 8, j = 2;
...
i = 8, j = 8;

i = 7, j = 1;
...
i = 7, j = 7

i = 6, j = 1
...
i = 6, j = 6
```

This goes on until you get to i = 1, j = 1.
Regarding the bubble sort I think you can find some nice visualisations online, something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67k3I2GxTH8

Answer (score 0):

In the code,
you see the inner loop is always iterating one time less than before.

This is because in bubble sort, at end of each iteration, the maximum element in 0 to (N - i)th array
(where N = size of array and i is the iteration number considering it varies from 1 to N) is put to its actual position

Lets take an example of array A = {2, 5, 6, 1, 9, 8}

After 1st iteration
A = {2, 5, 1, 6, 8, 9}

After 2nd iteration
A = {2, 1, 5, 6, 8, 9}

After 3rd iteration
A = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}

After 4th iteration
A = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}

After 5th iteration
A = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}

As you can see, after 1st iteration, 9 - the highest element, is at its correct position
Similarly in 2nd iteration 8 is, in 3rd iteration 6 is and so on.

Hope it was helpful.